# What setting do I need to be in to see colour?

Tags: light, color

I am new to Blender, been following Blender Guru videos... suddenly I can't see colour and I am really struggling with controlling the camera. I must have hit the wrong button...

He moves too fast for me to follow what he is clicking on often.

I guess my question is really... is it normal to watch videos 8-10 times and still be lost?

Comment: Well, it's not _abnormal_. Just take your time. Watch the same 10 second segment over and over if you have to. You can switch to "color" (render mode) by using the 4 little circles at the top right of the viewport (left to right - wireframe - solid - material preview - rendered). You can also change by pressing Z in the 3D viewport and selecting _Rendered_ or _Material Preview_ from the pie menu (the other 2 don't show color - solid is default when you open blender).

Comment: With Youtube videos you can also slow them down to quarter speed if you want to see what's going on. Click the gear wheel in the bottom right of the bar at the bottom and then click 'Playback speed'. You can pause the video and jump backwards a few seconds with the left arrow key on the keyboard too.

Answer (score 0):

I think everyone struggles a bit in the start. Just persist and keep watching his videos. I would also try Grant Abbit. He does a very good job of explaining the things and has lot's of videos for intermediate and beginners. For your colour question there is a screenshot of colour management in blender. Make sure that the settings are set to what I have here.[image]

Comment: First of all I don't think _Filmic_ is a good idea for new users that maybe don't know anything about color management,they might get confused when all colors look a little "washed out" and pure white is always just a light grey etc. Especially when you've set the _Look_ to _None_. For the start the _Standard_ setting is fine. And when he says suddenly he can't see color this sounds more like he changed _Shading_ options from _Material Preview_ to _Solid_ or he uses _Matcaps_ or anything.

Comment: My colour management settings are exactly the same as your screen shot. I think I somehow shut the light source off.

Comment: I had clicked on a different viewport shading button... or hit a shortcut by mistake. colour is back. Thank you!